# Java Memory Leak in using LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks

Dears,

My java application after a while of running throws an exception

Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

After monitoring jvm memory with using jprofiler I found that there is a memory leak in my codes.

in my program I send a lot snmp request to some devices and getting their response and push them into two LinkedBlockingQueue object.
there are some threads that poll from queue and process them and remove objects from queue. but it seems that the objects don't remove from queue. I can't see any problem in my codes.
any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

```
ResponseListener.java
public class ResponseListener{
    public void receiveResponse(){
                SNMPResultMessage resultMessage;
                    resultMessage = new SNMPResultMessage(
                            userObject.getDeviceId(),
                            oid,
                            deviceServiceId,
                            sensorId,
                            response.getVariable(oid).toInt(),
                            userObject.getTimestamp(),
                            Utils.getCreateDay(dt),
                            Utils.getQuarterOfDay(dt),
                            slaDisabled
                    );
                    Logger.debug("SNMP Request Response:" + resultMessage);                    

                PubSub.publish(resultMessage);

     }
}
```

PubSub.java

public class PubSub {

```
public static final BlockingQueue<ResultMessage> average = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
public static final BlockingQueue<ResultMessage> cassandra = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
public static void publish(ResultMessage message) {
    average.add(message);
    cassandra.add(message);
}



private PubSub() {
    /* prevent instantiation */
}
```

}

AverageWatcher.java

```
public class AverageWatcher implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                ResultMessage message = PubSub.average.take();
                if (message == null) {
                    if (numberOfChanges > 1000) {
                        insertBatch();
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                numberOfChanges++;
                if (changes.get(message.getSensorId()) == null) {
                    changes.put(message.getSensorId(), new HashSet<>());
                }
                changes.get(message.getSensorId()).add(new CreateDayQuarterOfDay(message.getCreateDay(), message.getQuarterOfDay()));
                if (numberOfChanges > 5000) {
                    insertBatch();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.error(ex.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

CassandraQueueWatcher.java

```
public class CassandraQueueWatcher implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                ResultMessage message = PubSub.cassandra.take();
                if (message == null) {
                    if (batchSize > 1000) {
                        insertBatch();
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                boolean violated = checkViolated(message);

                batch.add(
                        Cassandra.insertRawReportStmt
                                .bind()
                                .setInt("sensor_id", message.getSensorId())
                                .setInt("create_day", message.getCreateDay())
                                .setLong("create_time", message.getTimestamp() / 1000)
                                .setFloat("value", message.getValue())
                                .setBool("violated",violated)
                );
                batchSize++;
                if (batchSize > 2000) {
                    insertBatch();
                }
                message =  null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.error(ex.getCause());
        }
    }

}
```

in my codes, only in ResponseListener.java create new SNMPResultMessage objects. please take a look at the attached image.
[jprofiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUtGR.png)

Comment: What does `insertBatch` do?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Some early versions didn't unlink the head of the queue properly, preventing the nodes from being cleaned up.  http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6805775

Comment: insert batch in cassandraWatcher insert data into db and in averageWatcher it insert data into mysql   

java version "1.8.0_60"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)  

I'm running it on docker container

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is from the queues?  You should take a heap dump and find out where all the data is living.  It is very unlikely the error is in the queue rather your implementation.

Comment: @jo Did you see the screnshoot ? [jprofiler screenshoot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iUtGR.png),why is it generating  LinkedBlockingQueue instances ? I have only one object of type LinkedBlockingQueue

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the queue is filling up because you are inserting faster new messages than reading them.

Try checking the size of the queue or use the [bounded version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue(int)).